# does trac have a way to track diffs or changes made to reports?

Tags: trac

Does trac have a way to track changes made to reports? I've tried to do some research on this, but was unsuccessful. Ultimately, what I want to do is to be able to revert some SQL of a report to an earlier state.

Comment: Reports are not versioned by Trac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by RjOllos, reports are not versioned by trac. Good to know.